# How can I get the associate value of case from enum

Tags: swift, enums

How can I get the associate value of case from enum in swift? My following code seems ok. but however I clean up `getValue()`? Since it must be `[String]` return?

```
enum ColorName: {
    case naming([String])
    case rbg([String])

    var description: String {
        get { return String(describing: self) }
    }

    func getValue() -> [String] {
        switch self {
        case .naming(let num):
            return num
        case .rbg(let num):
            return num
        }
    }
}

let color = ColorName.naming(["blue", "red", "green"])
print(color.description) /// it should return naming since we return the name string
print(color.getValue()) /// get ["blue", "red", "green"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two cases - now you only need to write `return num` once.

```
// also consider making this a property instead
func getValue() -> [String] {
    switch self {
    case .naming(let num), .rbg(let num):
        return num
    }
}
```

If your enum only has these two cases, I would write this as a struct with a `[String]` property and an enum property.

```
struct Color {
    enum ColorType {
        case rgb
        case named
    }
    let type: ColorType
    let value: [String]
}
```